# error: key does not contain a section: newhaven

Tags: git, github, global, ssh-keys, git-config

I am just doing the pre-work for my coding bootcamp. I set up an SSH key and am working on my first git config. But when I try to `git config --global user.name`, I get the error code

> "error: key does not contain a section: newhaven"

I have hardly dipped my toes into this coding world because this is simply pre-work, and my tutor couldn't figure out how to resolve this error either.

Comment: What's in your per-user `.gitconfig` file? (It is likely in $HOME or %HOME or whatever your OS uses as the spelling, although on some systems it is in a sub-directory elsewhere.)

Comment: Hi there - how can I check this? super new to all of this, even using terminal

Comment: If you're on MacOS or Linux, in a shell / terminal window, you can `cat $HOME/.gitconfig` or `less $HOME/.gitconfig` to view it. (The `cat` command concatenates multiple files - so with one file name like this, it just copies that one file to your screen. The `less` command is a file-viewer and is the default Git pager.)